# Time Machine and Volume backup issue after Sierra update

Tags: backup, time-machine, disk-volume

I have updated to 10.12.5 yesterday and I am facing some issues with Time Machine and volumes where the backups are stored.
I used to have two Volumes where Time Machine backups are stored:

1. network volume
2. usb drive

The first problem I faced was that all the backups, either on network or on usb drive, stuck on "preparing backup" state.

I tried these solutions:

1. reset Time Machine (removing /Library/Preferences/com.apple.TimeMachine.plist
2. reset SMC and NVRAM

Nothing changed. Except for the fact that, since I reset Time Machine, my Volume with usb backup partition (HDMac) is not mountable anymore. Giving `sudo lsof | grep disk2s2` I understood that system stuck on `fsck_hfs`. While backup on network drive is still on "preparing backup".

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Did you upgrade to Sierra from 10.11.x? This would change *a lot of* files which could result in a longer than usual preparation step

Comment: @patrix: yes I updated from 10.11.x. But Time Machine stucks on "Preparing backup" for more than two hours. Is it a normal behavior?

Comment: Hmm, it may take hours. And after resetting TM it may take longer if some of the disks need to be checked first

Comment: @patrix ok, so I am going to wait. Thank you very much!

Comment: If it is still stuck after a day please update the question accordingly so we can dig deeper. Good luck!

Comment: @patrix it is just finished! So I can change the subject to Solve. Thanks again!

Comment: If you've solved your problem, write an answer and accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for my problem was simply waiting for some hours in order to obtain the backup.

To repair my usb drive I ran `fsck_hfs -fy /dev/disks2`.